# Select a value from dropdown containing duplicate values

Tags: drop-down-menu, cypress

Hi I am new to Cypress and trying to automate this scenario -

I have a dropdown like this having duplicate values:

```
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
```

Now I want to select the second Volvo that appears on the list. Things I have tried:

```
cy.get('select#cars').select('Volvo') //This selects the first Volvo
```

Edit: Now Based on the selection above, a new element is displayed on the webpage and I am checking the inner text of that element -

```
cy.get('selector', {timeout: 8000}).should('have.text', some text)
```

Comment: How do you know you are selecting the first? They are identical. How does the app behaviour differ if the first or the second is selected by the user?

Comment: Based on the selection a certain other element is displayed. And I am then validating  it using `cy.get('selector', {timeout: 8000}).should('have.text', some text)`.

Comment: There must be something different that triggers the other element.

Comment: You can use indexing `cy.get('select#cars').select('Volvo').eq(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the Cypress source code, the `.select()` command dispatches `input` and `change` events to the option chosen.

You can do the same, "manually" selecting

```js
cy.get('option').eq(1).then($option => {

  const input = new Event('input', { bubbles: true, cancelable: false })
  $option.get(0).dispatchEvent(input)

  const change = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents')
  change.initEvent('change', true, false)
  $options.get(0).dispatchEvent(change)
})
```

Ref: [cypress/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/actions
/select.ts](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/17ed1c9831054c5875e21d29c588a5ecb50edcbc/packages/driver/src/cy/commands/actions/select.ts#L300)

---

Also this works

```js
cy.get('option').eq(1)
  .trigger('input', { force: true })   
  .trigger('change', { force: true })  
  // force because select is not open so option isn't visible
```

While either way triggers events, it does not select the option.

This will do that,

```js
cy.get('option').eq(1)
  .trigger('input', { force: true }) 
  .trigger('change', { force: true })
  .then($option => {
    cy.get('select').then($select => $select.val($option.val()))
  })
```

Comment: Your answer is excellent! Can you add some links so we can learn?